# Sparx Enterprise Architect EA truncates diagrams in publishing process

Tags: report, enterprise-architect, publishing

While I run a report on some elements, BPMN diagrams are part of the report.
However, EA truncated the images on the rights and the lower side; instead of scaling them into the page.
I tried to adjust parameters according to https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/modeling_tools/scaletopage.html but there was no change in the re-published document.

Any idea what other switches could be used?

Inside my template, it looks like

```
diagram>
                              {Diagram.DiagramImage}
<diagram
```

and for each diagram, the Properties -> Diagram -> Advanced -> Scale to 1 page is selected.

Comment: How much is truncated, just a border, or like half the diagram?

Comment: it is a part from the border. Lets say, I have a BPMN process from left to right including 7 elements, plus start and stop. The stop is completly missing, the seventh element is mostly truncated. The same is with the lower border of the image. But, even small processes that definitily would fit the page are truncated (in the middle of the page, but ar the borders of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is that only the border of the image are cut off you might have an issue with incompatible settings.

These settings are relevant:

**Start | Desktop | Preferences | Diagram**

[image]

**Document generation options (F8)**

[image]

If you use multiple displays, with different DPI settings (at least one High DPI) you might also see issues like this.

Comment: What would be the recommendation here? Deselecting "Hiding Diagram Borders" (F8)?

Comment: I don't remember exactly. I just know that playing with these settings had an influence on this issue.